# Incomplete type error header -- how to fix?

Tags: c++

I thought I had a handle on how to fix circular dependencies, but I just can't fix the following, so I'd be grateful for any help!

I am writing a chess program and I have a class `Pieces`.

It's in file Pieces.cpp and includes Pieces.h.

Pieces.h **include** Rook.h.

Rook.h **include** ChessPiece.h

ChessPiece.h **include** ChessBoard.h.

Now,

ChessBoard.h **include** Pieces.h.

I have include guards everywhere, so it goes all right; except `ChessBoard` actually *owns* Pieces rather than just having Pointers/References to them:

```
private:
    Pieces black_pieces;
    Pieces white_pieces;
```

I did a forward declaration of `Pieces`, but the compiler complains about an incomplete type on this line. I can see why: at this point, the compiler does not know how much space to allocate for a class of type `Pieces`, though it knows one exists from my forward declaration.

My problem is that I want `ChessBoard` to store these `Pieces` objects, so I cannot simply have pointers to them. I suppose I could put them on the heap, but I've heard that using the heap is generally discouraged. Is this a case where maybe it would be useful, or is there a solution I am overlooking?

I hope my explanation is understandable even without posting the code -- there would be a lot of it!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to fully declare `Pieces` beforehand, correct. But you can simply do this, can’t you?

Comment: But how? My `Pieces` includes another header which includes `ChessBoard`. So when it runs through its preprocessor directives, it will always put `ChessBoard` ahead of `Pieces`...

Comment: Uhm, simply change the include order so that `Pieces.h` does *not* include `Rook.h` (or `Rook.h` doesn’t include `ChessBoard.h`), and instead *it* just gets to see a forward-declared version of `ChessBoard` (rather than the other way around as you have it at the moment).

Comment: The class in the *other* header, does it really need the full definition of `ChessBoard`, or can it manage with just a pointer/reference of `ChessBoard`? Or do you really need the full definitions in the other header file in `Pieces.h`?

Comment: I think I might have a deeper issue of understanding here. I have so far put all include directives in the header files rather than the implementations. If I do leave out the include directive in the other header, and just put in the forward declaration, how does it know how to run its methods later? Do I put the include directive in the implementation instead? Thank you for your help, sorry for being clueless.

Comment: OK, this seems to work. So far, I had always put all the dependencies in the header. But I now understand, I think, that you only have to do that if you actually need the full definition at that stage; otherwise you put it in the implementation. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it's often useful to put a forward declaration in a header and `#include` that type's actual definition in the corresponding source file.

Comment: If `ChessBoard` owns the `Pieces` it needs the complete type.  But do Pieces really need to know Rook, etc...  Could you give us more details about these dependencies (f.ex class definition) ?

Comment: OK, I understand now. For some reason, I'd thought our lecturer had said that you put both the include directive and the forward declaration in the header. I see now that that's really silly and obviously can't work. If anyone wants to post this answer, I'll mark it as the answer; if nobody has by tomorrow, I'll answer it myself. Thanks everyone for the quick and insightful responses to my somewhat opaque question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declarations work for member references and pointers.  When declaring instances of classes or structures in another class / structure, you need the full declaration.

Your question sounds like you have an issue with your design / architecture.
A `Rook` is-a `Chess_Piece`.  Fine, sounds good.

The class `Pieces` sounds ambiguous.
Do you need a specialized type for containing pieces or can you use `std::vector<Chess_Piece*>`?

A `Chessboard` should *contain* zero or more instances of `Chess_Piece`.  A common implementation is a 2d array of pointers to `Chess_Piece`.  The pointers help support polymorhphism.

Another implementation could be a vector of .  This is of the view that a chess board has pieces at different locations on the board.

**Edit 1:  Allocation of pieces**
I suggest having a *factory* which returns pointers to the pieces.  Since the quantity of pieces is known and won't change, they can be allocated as static, automatic variables.

```
class Piece_Factory
{
  static std::vector<Pawn> white_pawns;
  static std::vector<Pawn> black_pawns;
  static Queen             white_queen(white);
  static Queen             black_queen(black);
public:
  Piece_Factory()
  {
    Pawn wp(white);
    Pawn bp(black);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
      white_pawns.push_back(wp);  // Append a copy to the vector.
      black_pawns.push_back(bp);
    }
  }
  Chess_Piece * get_white_pawn(unsigned int index)
  {
    return &white_pawn[index];
  }
  Chess_Piece * get_white_queen(void)
  {
    return &white_queeen;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

If I do go for the vector of pointers, where should I store the actual `Chess_Piece`s pointed to?

Comment: Since the number of chess pieces is fixed, you could declare them as file local variables and return pointers to them; no need for dynamic memory.  This is similar to what we are doing on our embedded systems to prevent the need for dynamic allocation.